# How to delete selected item in a ListView android xamarin

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, xamarin

How to delete selected items in a ListView,The Items of ListView are from SQLite.net Database
below is my code but when i delete all row and add new item to db ,i can not delete a row from listview

```
private void popmenu(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = new PopupMenu(this, listnames.GetChildAt(e.Position));
        menu.Inflate(Resource.Layout.popup_menu);
        menu.MenuItemClick += (s, A) =>
        {
            switch (A.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.pop_button1:
                    // update stuff
                    string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");
                    db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
                    var data = db.Table<LoginTable>();
                    // Toast.MakeText(this, "row:" + (e.Position+1), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    int ww =(e.Position + 1);
                    var data1 = data.Where(x => x.id == ww);
                    foreach (var item in data1)
                    {
                        db.Delete(item);

                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Delete Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }

                        break;

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a remove item function in the code of your adapter for example:

```
public class MainAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{

   private List<string> items = new List<string>();
   private Activity context;

   public MainAdapter(Activity context, List<string> items) : base()
   {
         this.context = context;
         this.items = items;
   }

   ...

   public void RemoveItemAt(int position)
   {
      items.RemoveAt(position);
   }

}
```

Then in the item click event:

```
private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    adapter.RemoveItemAt(e.Position);
    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[image]

Comment: then how remove from database?

Comment: @hamid, if your row id is the same as the order of your list items, then you can use `e.position` as id to delete the item from your db, maybe you can check this blog: [Example of Deleting from SQLite DB using C# in Xamarin Android](http://slackshotindustries.blogspot.sg/2013/06/deleting-from-db-using-sqlite-in-android.html) .